# When I use my Event Sytem with Unity Inspector value pass via the Raise method is always false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, event-handling

My event system code (preleminar):

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "SO/Game Event")]
public class GameEvent : ScriptableObject
{
  private readonly List<GameEventListener> _listeners = new();
  public void Raise() { _listeners.OfType<GameEventListenerVoid>().ForEach(l => l.OnEventRaised()); }
  public void Raise(bool value) { _listeners.OfType<GameEventListenerBool>().ForEach(l => l.OnEventRaised(value)); }
  public void RegisterListener(GameEventListener listener) { _listeners.Add(listener); }
  public void UnregisterListener(GameEventListener listener) { _listeners.Remove(listener); }
}

[Serializable]
public class BoolEvent : UnityEvent<bool> { }

[Serializable]
public abstract class GameEventListener : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField]
  private GameEvent _gameEvent;
  private void OnEnable() { _gameEvent.RegisterListener(this); }
  private void OnDisable() { _gameEvent.UnregisterListener(this); }
}

[Serializable]
public class GameEventListenerBool : GameEventListener
{
  [SerializeField] public BoolEvent Response;
  public void OnEventRaised(bool value) { Response.Invoke(value); }
}

[Serializable]
public class GameEventListenerVoid : GameEventListener
{
  [SerializeField] public UnityEvent Response;
  public virtual void OnEventRaised() { Response.Invoke(); }
}
```

It make me able to create assets for my differents event over the game.
[image: Assest]

After that I specify GameEvent on my script will raise event:

```
public GameEvent Toggle;
...
Toggle.Raise(_isOn);
```

And instrument the inspector with the specific Asset

[image: Specify Asset]

And on my other GameObject I add the listener via Inspector and link with corresponding method

[image]

The method is :

```
public void ToggleMusic(bool value) //The parameter value is always false ?
{
  if (value) SourceAmbiance.Play();
  else SourceAmbiance.Stop();
}
```

Why the parameter value is always false ?

I follow the call with debug. And the parameter is ok till I hit Response.Invoke() in my GameEventListener where the value is ok. But not in the final method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looking at the screen shot of the  GameEventListenerBool script, your boolean value is always false.  You may have selected the static version of this method to be called.  Select the DropDown again and see if there is a `ToggleMusic` method in the dynamic section.

Comment: Thank you verry much this verry helpfull :-)

Comment: ...Did it work?

Comment: Yes you solved my problem somthing I learned today :-)